# Split a struct into a tuple

Tags: c++, tuples, metaprogramming

The question is pretty straight, how could I generate :

```
std::tuple<float, int, double>
```

If I know the type :

```
struct Foo { float a; int b; double c; };
```

And how could I retrieve the data, in both convertion?

Comment: There are no features in the C++ language itself to effect this kind of a type conversion. You will have to do it yourself.

Comment: The normal answer is that you cannot. C++ doesn't have the reflection required to do this. Of course you can add your own preprocessor script that parses the declaration and generates the tuple. There is also some UB-based boost thing that is not supposed to work but does anyways.

Comment: You'd need reflection. You can do something like that using [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get), but it will only work with pod types.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Thanks for the link to **magic_get**. I was looking for that. Here is the [talk at CppCon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abdeAew3gmQ) that explains it in great details.

Comment: We need clarification on "And how could I retrieve the data, in both convertion [sic]?"  What is your desired _convention_ of retrieving data for tuple?  Is it `std::get<0>(some_foo)`?

Comment: @Wyck: That is how data is retrieved from a tuple, yes.

Comment: All users: The comments are for ***on-topic*** clarification of posts only. They are not for the kind of bickering I just cleaned up. Do not restart that discussion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do this in C++, as it would require a language feature known as *reflection*.

Instead, "manually" build the tuple or just begin with a tuple in the first place.

Alternatively, you could build a script in Python (or similar) to preprocess your code and auto-generate the resulting conversion.

Comment: I was hoping some improvement with C++17 or even C++20. Well that's a shame I guess :)

Comment: Upvoted for the last sentence. Sometime I would prefer Python instead of ugly metaprogramming...

Comment: Indeed. There's nothing wrong with a nice pre-build step. I have a list of "message types" and their logical fields, in a text file, that Python will "compile" into C++ classes for me resplendent with all the ugly boilerplate they require. It's lovely.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a conversion operator.

```
struct Test {
    int a;
    float b;
    double c;

    explicit operator std::tuple<int, float, double>() const {
       return {a, b, c};
    }
};
```

Then, use it like that:

```
int main() {
    Test t{12, 3.2f, 4.5};
    std::tuple tt = t; 
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://godbolt.org/g/AUttS5)</kbd>

Comment: But I can't write `std:get<0>(t);`  which may arguably be the desired use case.

Comment: @Wyck I don't know if it's the desired semantics. OP didn't ask that specifically, unless I didn't understood the question correctly.

Answer (score 3):

As other answer said, there is no way to do this in a generic way in C++14.

However, there is a trick in C++17 that uses structured bindings:

```
template<typename T>
auto as_tuple_ref( T & t )
{
   auto &[a,b,c] = t;
   return std::tie(a,b,c);
}

struct Foo { float a; int b; double c; };

Foo bar;
int & b_ref = std::get<1>( as_tuple_ref(bar) );
```

This version only works for structures with 3 members, but I believe that with some time and effort (and some SFINAE) it is possible to write a fully generic solution (and it will probably involve a lot of copy-paste).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it manually.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using std::tuple;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::get;

struct Foo { float a; int b; double c; };

int main()
{
  auto tuple_foo = tuple<decltype(Foo::a), decltype(Foo::b), decltype(Foo::c)>{1.1f, 10, 100.001};
  cout << "<0>: " << get<0>(tuple_foo) << endl;
  cout << "<1>: " << get<1>(tuple_foo) << endl;
  cout << "<2>: " << get<2>(tuple_foo) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Then what's the point with `auto`? Why don't you just `tuple<...> f = {...}`?

Comment: @user202729: You could do that too. Some people are obsessed with `auto` ;)

Comment: @user202729 • I've adopted the advice of my coworker Herb Sutter:  https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: @Eljay: That's a fairly strong interpretation of the phrase _"The jury is still out on whether to recommend this one wholesale, as we’re still trying it out"_

Comment: Oh gosh I should have say automatically sorry... I ran into boost hana code for this stuff... Seems like it's going to be a pain in the ass

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit • that was from 2013.  Since then, its been tried out, and the jury has come back.

Comment: @Eljay: I'm sorry to hear that. AAA is a horrible way to code.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel: lol :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit • Tom, I will be happy to pass along your sentiments to my colleagues.

Comment: @Eljay: Not sure why they would care but up to you

Answer (score 0):

Based on those member names, i.e.: the 1st member is called `a`, the 2nd `b`, and the 3rd `c`. You can define the following struct template, `member_type<>`, to pick up the type of each individual member:

```
template<typename T>
struct member_type : T {
    using a_t = decltype(T::a);   
    using b_t = decltype(T::b);   
    using c_t = decltype(T::c);   
};
```

With this alias template, `tuple_splitter<>`, you can define a tuple from a `struct` with such members (named `a`, `b` and `c`):

```
template<typename T>
using tuple_splitter = std::tuple
                 <
                    typename member_type<T>::a_t,
                    typename member_type<T>::b_t,
                    typename member_type<T>::c_t
                 >;
```

Then, for your `Foo`:

```
tuple_splitter<Foo> foo_tuple;
```

`foo_tuple` will have the type `std::tuple<float, int, double>`.

If you define now a new `struct`, `Bar`, as:

```
struct Bar { int a; char b; float c; };
```

Then:

```
tuple_splitter<Bar> bar_tuple;
```

`bar_tuple` will be of type `std::tuple<int, char, float>`.

Answer (score 0):

Using std::tie even makes it easier:

```
struct foo
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
    string str;
};

void main()
{
    std::tuple<int, int, string> a{ 1, 1, "Hello " };
    foo b;
    std::tie(b.value1, b.value2, b.str) = a;
}
```